# Why does my included/required file with variables stop working when I upload everything?

Tags: php

My index.php gets all parts for the website seperated and it looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'var1.php';
?>

<?php
include 'var2.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/head.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/header.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/content.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/footer.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/bottom.php';
?>
```

The main parts like head, header etc. are always the same but for each city I need different variables and thatswhy I got a folder (for example 'Berlin') with only index.php, var1.php and var2.php in it.

This is working fine on my computer but as soon as I upload it to get it online, the variables from var1.php and var2.php are not included anymore.

Can anyone see something wrong here?

Comment: And you are sure that `var1.php` and `var2.php` actually got copies up to the live server? And to the right directory??

Comment: In what specific way does it fail?  What is the error?  What code produces that error?  What do the PHP logs tell you?

Comment: I'm sure and even if I add them directly above the html it doesn't work. Variables at all are not working :/ Not even an errorcode.. just not echoing

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Added it but it shows nothing. It's like echo is not working. Including works but in my text the added variables are not shown they are just empty. For example I have a button to press call with my phonenumber in it but its empty too. Do I have to add something to get it work or is it probably because of the seperating?

Comment: the thing is, that I have include the head.php from a different folder. If I have all in the same folder, then it works but I need them to have from different folders

Comment: Change the include to a require and see what shows then

Comment: OH Now we get to it! So you will have to change the include to be `include 'relatibe/path/to/var1.php';`

Comment: no wait. I have the right path and there is no error. it just dont takes the variables from it. like if its not accepting other paths?!

Comment: <?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/berlin/var1.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/berlin/var2.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/head.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/header.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/content.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/footer.php';
?>

<?php
include 'https://www.example.de/city/bottom.php';
?> not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with:

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/city/head.php');